# Does Office365Users() connector allow to get these info Employee ID & Position

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

We want to show the following information for a selected user (inside a People picker field), inside inside Power Apps:

1. Manager  ---> inside a People or Group field
2. Position/Job Title ---> inside a free text field
3. Department ---> inside a drop-down field
4. Employee ID ---> inside a free test field

Now based on this documentation @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-office365-users the Office365Users allow us to get the Manager & Department.

But does it support getting these 2 information also "Position/job-Title" & "Employee ID"?

If not, then is there another connector we can use to show these info?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the job title of user using `jobTitle` property.

For example:

```
Office365Users.MyProfileV2().jobTitle
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

I am not sure about fetching employee id directly using Power Apps. But, as per the documentation of [Get user profile (V2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/#get-user-profile-(v2)) action,

> This action retrieves the profile of a specific user. Learn more about available fields to select: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user#properties

It is possible to read the `employeeId` & `id` (Azure AD id) of user using this action.

Also, check below threads if it helps:

1. [Get EmployeeID on Powerapps](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Get-EmployeeID-on-Powerapps/td-p/819602)
2. [Unable to get EmployeeID](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Unable-to-get-EmployeeID/td-p/117080)